# CMS page code being "rewritten" upon save

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, forms

Magento CE 1.9.0.1 on dev environment running Ubuntu, Apache, PHP, MySQL - that's it.

Not a lot to this one: I'm trying to add some attributes to an input field within my CMS homepage. It's a single CMS page.

I try to change this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" />
```

To This:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="text">
```

And it continuously reverts back to the first example. Sometimes it will save, allow me to refresh the page 2 or 3 times showing the second, correct version and then it will show me the first version again. I don't get it and I can't explain it. The CMS section is also stripping white space out of my CMS pages that I intentionally insert to make the code more readable but that isn't my primary concern right now. Has anyone seen behavior like this in a vanilla install of Magento on a minimal development environment (or otherwise)? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394325/stop-magento-fixing-html-in-static-blocks

Answer (score 1):

I am running Magento 1.9.2.1.

Here is my experience with cms:
I am trying to insert HTML and inline CSS.  For example:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 450px; background-image: url('{{media url="myimages/asdf.jpg"}}');">
```

Please note: I can get my code to appear properly on the front-end.  But when I hit save, my CMS code changes and it is not being rendered properly in the admin pages HTML editor!  Here is what I see when I go back:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 450px; background-image: url('{{media url=;">
```

In addition, Magento likes to make other types of changes for me.  For example, if I insert a CMS tag

```
{{media url=...}}
```

I might all of a sudden find it is surrounded with:

```
<p>{{media url=...}}</p>
```

Please stop changing my code!  How to disable/fix?