# Problems with saving CMS page changes in Magento-1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, wysiwyg, tinymce, ce-1.9.2.1

I have some problems that I hope you can provide advice.
I newly installed Magento 1.9.2.1 and noticed strange behavior when i save something.

1. From the Navigation bar,  I enter the the default 'about us' CMS page,and when I try to change the contents by copy and paste html data from my original site via the wysiwyg editor , and then click 'save and continue', I get at 403 error and the changes cannot be saved.
2. I tried to create product data and when I try to make changes to specifically **the description** of product data by copy and pasting it with html tags and then click 'save and continue', The changes cannot be saved and there is not even any error message displayed.

There are no third party module being installed.

Please advise on how I can resolve the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would start by checking the file permissions on your server, and the privileges of your MySQL user. If they are correct, check that your server has been properly set up and meets the minimum requirements of Magento. Additionally, try setting up Magento in a virtual environment and compare its database with yours to make sure that no tables/indices are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For a partial answer, I would encourage you to look here:

[CMS page code being "rewritten" upon save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72333/cms-page-code-being-rewritten-upon-save/99624#99624)

The reason is, I believe if you are not seeing your changes saved, magento does not like your changes and refuses to save them.